# Exchange in the Netherlands - Working Holiday or Residence Visa

Tags: visa, netherlands, australian-citizens, working-holiday-visas

I (an Australian citizen) am going on exchange to the Netherlands. Apparently it is much cheaper (about $400AUD) and much less paperwork to get a working holiday visa than a residence visa. However, the info sent by my university says:

> As Dutch embassies in Canada, Australia and New-Zealand have frequently discouraged the use of the WHP and WHS for an exchange study period, we strongly advise to NOT consult the Dutch embassy on this subject and simply travel to the Netherlands with all required documents.

How serious a risk am I taking by relying on receiving a working holiday visa on arrival?

Comment: That sounds a bit dubious; I feel like asking which university but I know you probably wouldn't want to disclose that. I guess I _might_ consider the risk based on how much I would trust the particular university, but in the end telling you to avoid an embassy's instructions is risky.